# Ordered Dynamo Map Structure? (without using marshalerl)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any Dynamo structure that functions like a LinkedHashMap in Java that I would not need to create a custom marshaller for?

As a side question, list ordering in Dynamo is preserved correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DynamoDB supports the following types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes):

Scalars and scalar sets: N, NS, S, SS, B, BS, Null, Boolean

Documents: Map, List

Ordered maps are not among the supported types. You would need to create a custom marshaller if using the Mapper for a LinkedHashMap.

List order is preserved. Set order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent an order-preserving map as a list of key/value pairs:

```
[
  {"key": "one", "value": ... },
  {"key": "two", "value": ... },
  ...
]
```

It's relatively easy to do the translation without resorting to a custom marshaller/unmarshaller:

```java
@DynamoDBDocument
public class MapEntry {
    private String key;
    private Whatever value;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName="whatever")
public class YourTable {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, Whatever> map;

    @DynamoDBIgnore // Don't store this directly or order will be lost
    public LinkedHashMap<String, Whatever> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(LinkedHashMap<String, Whatever> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    // mapper will save/load using these instead; convert between
    // map and list of entries on the fly.

    public List<MapEntry> getMapEntries() {
        if (map == null) return null;

        List<MapEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Whatever> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            entries.add(new MapEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }

        return entries;
    }

    public void setMapEntries(List<MapEntry> entries) {
        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Whatever>();
        for (MapEntry entry : entries) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that you don't spell numbers in English all day, instead you could build strings from the numbers using Integer.toString(##).